Is it possible to send arbitrary data (not TCP or UDP) through a socket, while allowing the kernel to do the IP encapsulation for me?
Suppose I want to implement my own transport layer protocol. If I open a socket with:
int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

or
int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

then this is not satisfactory since (I think), the kernel/network stack will automatically wrap any data we send as TCP or UDP, respectively (i.e. it will put the appropriate headers in front of our payload).
If I do:
int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

then this is too far in the other direction, now the kernel expects me to provide it with a pre-formatted IP datagram, so I have to implement the internet protocol myself as well.
Is there a way to get the "sweet spot", where I can do my own transport protocol but let the sockets library do all the IP encapsulation for me?

@SteffenUllrich Ahhhh, I see - and it's set by default, if you use IPPROTO_RAW? Or at least it appears to be getting set by default on my system.

I've reverted my suggestion for disabling IP_HDRINCL. IPPROTO_RAW implies this since the transport protocol specification is part of the IP header. So if you want to do your own transport protocol, you must also define the IP header.

@SteffenUllrich Yes, so if I understand correctly the purpose of the third argument to socket (at least in this case) is purely to set the "protocol" field in the IP header. So for example if you set SOCK_RAW and IPPROTO_TCP, the OS will still not generate TCP headers and implement the TCP protocol for you. Instead, it will simply set the protocol field in the IP header to the appropriate value, and then expect you to prepare TCP segments yourself.

It is to set the protocol when sending and filter the packets for only this protocol when receiving. Maybe you can set your own custom protocol there also.
